# How to set up Geoserver app-schema feature chaining?

Tags: geoserver, xml, gml, geoserver-app-schema

I am using Geoserver 2.12 with the application schema plugin to map a PostGIS database schema to the GeodesyML schema. I need to set up a WFS request that returns GeodesyML output such as:

```
<wfs:member>
  <geo:GeodesyML gml:id="geoml_monuments.fid-39d8a647_15cd161ff6e_-7e89">
     <geo:Site>
        <geo:installedDate>2001-09-12T06:00:00Z</geo:installedDate>
     </geo:Site>
     <geo:Monument>
        <geo:height />
        <geo:foundation />
     </geo:Monument>
     <geo:siteLog>
        <geo:siteIdentification>
           <geo:siteName>Cordell, OK</geo:siteName>
           <geo:fourCharacterID>SG19</geo:fourCharacterID>
        </geo:siteIdentification>
        <geo:siteLocation>
           <geo:city>Norman</geo:city>
           <geo:state>Oklahoma</geo:state>
           <geo:countryCodeISO>United States</geo:countryCodeISO>
           <geo:tectonicPlate>North America</geo:tectonicPlate>
           <geo:approximatePositionITRF>
              <geo:cartesianPosition>
                 <gml:Point gml:id="cart.geoml_monuments.fid-39d8a647_15cd161ff6e_-7e89" />
              </geo:cartesianPosition>
              <geo:geodeticPosition>
                 <gml:Point gml:id="latlon.geoml_monuments.fid-39d8a647_15cd161ff6e_-7e89" srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:pos>-98.977854677 35.355545782</gml:pos>
                 </gml:Point>
              </geo:geodeticPosition>
           </geo:approximatePositionITRF>
        </geo:siteLocation>
     </geo:siteLog>
  </geo:GeodesyML>
```

I have succeeded in doing this when the data is all stored in a single materialized view in my database. Unfortunately this is too limiting and I need to be able to pull things from multiple views. Specifically I want to be able to pull the `geodeticPosition` and `cartesianPosition` geometry objects from a PostGIS view called `location_view` and all the rest of the data from `site_view`. I believe the way to do this is by [Feature Chaining](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/app-schema/feature-chaining.html) wherein I need to set up a top level mapping file which pulls data from `site_view` and `<Include>`s a second mapping file that pulls from `location_view`. **In each of these mapping files, what do I need to have in the `<targetElement>`, `<targetAttribute>`, `<linkElement>`, `<linkField>`, and `<sourceExpression>` fields?** Alternatively, is there an easier way to pull data from two different tables/views into a single mapping file?

[Here is an example provided from the Geoserver docs on Feature Chaining](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B56WW14iBz8BNnBTalZ0WlJUYk0?usp=sharing)